# evaluating result of jquery ajax with "application/javascript" & eval

Tags: jquery, ajax, eval

(FWIW, it is for my GPLv3+ [melt-monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) free software, to be later connected with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); so I'm aiming multi-stage meta-programming with sort-of mobile continuations....)

I want to have an AJAX request returning dynamically generated javascript code to be evaluated in the browser (that code is expected to be safe, and my application is a specialized HTTP server).

If I read [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation correctly, I have to code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'ajax_eval',
     method: 'POST',
     data: { something: what },
     dataType: 'script',
     success: function(gotdata) {
     }})
```

That AJAX request would get a reply containing several Javascript definitions, e.g.

```
 var somevar = somefunc();
 function foo(arg) {
 };
 someotherfunc(foo(somevar));
```

but I want the downloaded dynamic script to be evaluated in a global context, like [$.globalEval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) does. Will that work?
and what is the role of the `gotdata` argument to the success `function`? Does it hold the javascript text or its evaluated result (of the last downloaded expression, i.e. of `someotherfunc(foo(somevar))`)?

Also, how can I debug such stuff with a recent Firefox? In other words, does Firebug keep the exchanged script in memory to help debugging and give meaningful location for javascript errors?